# MySql counting all those tupples where in Date Rows containing (NULL) and or '0000-00-00' values

Tags: php, mysql, date, count

i want to count all those rows from mysql table where in the **"where clause"** three columns having two possible values in it. i.e. (`NULL`) and OR `0000-00-00`. For this i have written the following sql which returns a result where i am not sure it is a perfect sql query or not. Please guide me if i am doing wrong.

```
      SELECT 
          COUNT(sno) AS totalCases 
      FROM
         myTable
       WHERE (dateOfTransferInstituion IS NULL OR dateOfTransferInstituion = '0000-00-00')
         AND 
             (date_remanded IS NULL OR date_remanded = '0000-00-00')
         AND 
             (date_restored IS NULL OR date_restored = '0000-00-00')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't see any actual problem here

Comment: Dear Dagon it means that this will result correct result?

Comment: how would i know? its your db, so TEST IT and find out

Comment: ya sure you are right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read your task and I think your query is correct, but it is possible to do it more elegantly, like this  :

```
  SELECT 
      COUNT(sno) AS totalCases 
  FROM
     myTable
   WHERE IFNULL(dateOfTransferInstituion,'0000-00-00') = '0000-00-00'
     AND 
         IFNULL(date_remanded,'0000-00-00') = '0000-00-00'
     AND 
         IFNULL(date_restored,'0000-00-00') = '0000-00-00'
```

Comment: Dear @EntGriff thanks for your valuable response. I have tested both the quires and find that your query takes apx: 0.171 sec while my query taking 0.121 sec over the table wherein 181852 rows. Now i am not sure which query would be the best solution in situation where huge record exists?

Comment: @AbdulRahman i understood what you said, i think that my query is more elegant but if first parameter of function 'ifnull' mostly is null, it will be slowly than your query.

So I advise you to use your query, becouse as you said - it takes less time